# Should each database context be in its own Visual Studio Project?

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a project called MyApp.DataAccess which contains several database contexts.  This started as one context and has grown to three (all separate databases required for my app).  As you can imagine I have Initializer classes for each as well and I'm also now trying to use Migrations.  I can see that this will really clutter up my MyApp.DataAccess project.

I also have a project called MyApp.Model which contains model classes which are generally organized in folders per their use in each aforementioned Context.

**I'm struggling with how best to organize multiple DbContexts and Model classes.**

My instinct tells me option 1 but what is the best practice?

1. Create a MyApp.DataAccess.[ContextName] project for each DbContext which contains the DbContext, migrations, and relevant Model classes.  Ultimately I'll still need a MyApp.Model project to represent non-database Model classes.
2. Create a MyApp.DataAccess.[ContextName] project for each DbContext which contains ONLY the DbContext and Migrations; continue to use the MyApp.Model for ALL model classes (organized in folders and sub-namespaces).
3. Do nothing -- a single MyApp.DataAccess with multiple DbContexts, multiple migrations, etc.; a single MyApp.Model with Models for multiple databases organized by folder.

What is the best practice / ideal approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question should start with "why should I have different DbContexts". In most cases different contexts mean different data models, different - unrelated - responsibilities, and thus should be as well separated as that's possible. Which means that different assemblies are go.

Comment: I want to argue with you about willy-nilly creating separate projects for everything, as this can lead to over-design and slow loading/building projects... but in this case you are right on.

Comment: FYI your answer did come across a bit snarky... your title must be Architect. :-)

Comment: @kingdango You should also remember that assemblies provide you with encapsulation, allowing to hide all irrelevant (to domain) classes (as mapping, migrations and even DbContext) from consumer.